# Creating Clickable MAP for Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating an app which is going to have a map of some areas/block like shown in picture. I want to whenever click on any block of the  map specific information about that block is shown in separate layout. I may use google maps but how i add events against all given blocks on map? Here are sample pictures.

[image]

[image]

Comment: so are these areas indoor or outdoor? what I mean to say is do they have different GPS Coordinates?

Comment: these areas are outdoor

Comment: You can use `GroundOverlay` as described here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay and attach them respective blocks.